# InnerSVG is empty for SVG element in IE11

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-11

I try to get property `innerSVG` value and catch `undefined`.
[image]

Do not see please to console content, i've used `jQuery('#main_svg')[0].innerSVG`

Comment: Do you have loaded the [library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/innersvg/)?

Comment: What for i need the library?

Comment: There is no innerSVG property in any standard. It is an invention of this library to port innerHTML to SVG content. So, either use this library, or [Snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.innerSVG), which has a innerSVG() function, or do not use it at all.

Comment: You're wrong, innerHTML also `undefined`

Comment: I didn't say `innerHTML` would work. In fact, the library was written *because* it doesn't work in older browsers. The [DOM Parsing and Serialization spec](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dfn-fragment-serializing-algorithm) is relatively young and seems not to be implemented for IE11

Comment: Could you provide proof link about IE11?

Comment: Look at this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBKpoj). For Firefox and Chrome, it shows the source text of the circle in a paragraph below.  If IE11 does, it understands `innerHTML. If not, it does not implement the quoted spec.

Comment: What does the library above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no innerSVG property in any standard. According to [DOM Parsing and Serialization spec](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dom-element-innerhtml) `Element.innerHTML` should work also for SVG or other XML content.

In 2009, a library [innnerSVG](https://code.google.com/archive/p/innersvg/) was published to

> provide the innerHTML property on all SVGElements

Which apparently, at that time, did not work in all browsers. It contains its own implementation of a XML serializer. The numerous `TODO` comments in the source code seem to indicate it is a fairly incomplete.

Since Internet Explorer 9, it is no longer really needed, as there is support for `XMLSerializer`. While IE 11 seems to have a bug and does not return content for `innerHTML`, this will work:

```
function getInnerHTML (el) {
   if (el.innerHTML === undefined) {
       var XMLS = new XMLSerializer();
       var nodes = [];
       for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
         nodes.push(XMLS.serializeToString(el.childNodes[i]));
       }
       return nodes.join('');
   } else {
       return el.innerHTML;
   }
}
```

Comment: i need replace inner svg structure in ie, what should i do?
in other browsers i use `svg.innerHTML = someXML;`

Comment: I havn't tested it, but [this function](https://github.com/dnozay/innersvg-polyfill/blob/master/innersvg.js#L61) is supposed to work.