# `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML=document.getElementById('id').innerHTML` changes the website

Tags: html, dom, google-chrome-devtools

Here is what the website looks like at first:

[image: buttons]

I run

```js
document.getElementById('top-level-buttons').innerHTML = document.getElementById('top-level-buttons').innerHTML
```

Here is what the website looks like now:

[image: button outline only]

Why is this happening?

It is worth noting that this is an issue present in Chrome DevTools. Here are some observations that I have made:

- The button tags contain inside them `svg` tags. These `svg` tags are getting removed, which is why the content inside the buttons disappear.
- Clicking on "Copy Element" in the Chrome Inspect tab removes these `svg` tags, so I have to copy the `svg` tags separately
- Running the command noted above in the "Console" tab also removes the `svg` tags from the website

Any idea why this is happening? This issue could be specific to Chrome DevTools, or it could be not; I have no way of testing this. The website is [YouTube Music](https://music.youtube.com) and the div in question is `top-level-buttons`, which displays the Shuffle, Play, Add To Library, and Radio buttons on pages like playlists, albums, and artists.

Comment: Without having much of code we can't validate this. I am sure that it is not because of SVG tag inside the buttons. You can test it using fiddle with the sample codes. For example https://jsfiddle.net/8cghowq0/

Comment: can you provide the sample code, so that we could see where the issue is ?

Comment: I'm observing this in the YouTube Music web app. To replicate, go to [this](https://music.youtube.com/playlist?list=OLAK5uy_mA5AnlP2opezyhaMV9jZJ8A7iXUsj8Vq0) link. If you paste the JS code I've included above into the Chrome Console tab, the buttons change. If you want to view the code, you can press Ctrl + Shift + C and click on the buttons near the top (play and add to library).

Comment: Probably because SVG is XML inside, not HTML.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46691301/15242140) post says that it should work. Also, any suggestions for how I can achieve what I want to do? I want to get everything in this DIV, add an element, and set the DIV equal to that again. Basically, I'm developing a plugin for YouTube Music, and I want to add a button beside the other ones. Any ideas for how I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Assigning to innerHTML is the wrong approach for multiple reasons, primarily security and the fact that it destroys the event listeners attached to the elements via addEventListener. Use DOM manipulation like document.createElement(), after(), before(), prepend(), append(), insertAdjacentElement().

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried that, passing the element I wanted to add as a string. The SVG is still omitted. That is, I'm passing the SVG on in the string, but the element that gets added lacks the SVG (but has everything else like border, fill, etc). Any suggestions for workarounds?

Comment: The site is removing them as can be seeen by attaching MutationObserver, so just protect your content by placing it inside Shadow DOM.

Comment: You are right; I can see the events by using a MutationObserver. I'm not very familiar with Shadow DOM though. Could you post some demo code for my use case? Also, feel free to turn this into an answer!